# On the quotation mark around Method option in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

I note that in the documents about `NDSolve` or its variants, the main `Method` option has no quotation mark while its sub-`Method` option has a quotation mark in general.

Taking an example from the document:

```
 splittingsol = NDSolve[system, StartingStepSize -> 1/10, 
                Method -> {"Splitting", "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, 
                "Equations" -> {Y2, Y1, Y1}, "Method" -> {"LocallyExact"}}]
```

Note in the above example, we do only care about the syntax, especially those about `Method` options.

**Questions:**

Whether or not the quotation mark around the sub-`Method` option is necessary? If yes, what is the effect of the quotation mark and how do you determine if a quotation mark should be used for an option in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is mainly for historical reasons. Initially, all options where symbols. At a later stage it became apparent that option names from functions will fill the name space of available function names, so string options were introduced to mitigate that a bit. You can always use the string version of an option name; it will give the same result (well for NDSolve and related functions, but I'd guess for others too)

See that these options lead to the same result:

```
optionsFun[opt___] := 
 NDSolve[{x''[t] + 0.001 x[t] == t Sin[\[Pi] t] UnitStep[1 - t], 
   x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 25000}, opt]

r1 = optionsFun[StartingStepSize -> 0.1];
r2 = optionsFun["StartingStepSize" -> 0.1];

r1 === r2
True
```

In this case we get a different result because the option value is different:

```
r3 = optionsFun[StartingStepSize -> 10^-6];
r1 === r3
False
```

So quotation marks are mostly needed for sub-method options and can be used for first level options. The point is that using "Quoted" method options should always works, while there are cases for which the unquoted version will not work. However, you can find plenty of examples where both work. So the upshot is that I believe you will always get away with using quotes but not with using symbols.

As a side note, it is always, always, always better to include a working example of what you want to discuss. Make it as easy as possible for others to help you.

Comment: "So quotation marks are generally needed for sub-method options…" It's not true t least for `NDSolve`, isn't it?: `NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == Sin[t], 
  u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 Method -> {MethodOfLines, 
   SpatialDiscretization -> {TensorProductGrid, MaxPoints -> 25, MinPoints -> 25, 
     DifferenceOrder -> 4}}]`

Comment: Correct, but the point is that this works: `NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
  u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 25,
      "MinPoints" -> 25, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]`

Comment: @xzczd, I tried to clarify a bit what I meant. Hope this is better now. Thanks.